# C# Get Active NIC IPv4 Address

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have multiple network cards on my computer. (Because of VMWare)

How can I find the IPv4 address of the active card. I mean if I send a ping in a terminal and intercept packet in WireShark, I want the address of "Source".

I thought of checking every network interface and look if GateWay is empty or null ? Or maybe ping 127.0.0.1 and get the IP source of the ping request ? But cannot implement it.

For now I have this code which i found on StackOverFlow

```
 public static string GetLocalIpAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            return host.AddressList.First(h => h.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
        }
```

But it gets me the IP of the VmWare card. But I don't know what else that "`.First()`" I could use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have finally found an efficient way of getting the real IP. Basically it looks for all interfaces in IPv4, that are UP and the thing that makes it decide, is it only takes the interface with a default gateway.

```cs
public static string GetLocalIpAddress() {
    foreach(var netI in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
        if (netI.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 &&
            (netI.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet ||
                netI.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)) continue;
        foreach(var uniIpAddrInfo in netI.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Where(x => netI.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Count > 0)) {

            if (uniIpAddrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork &&
                uniIpAddrInfo.AddressPreferredLifetime != uint.MaxValue)
                return uniIpAddrInfo.Address.ToString();
        }
    }
    Logger.Log("You local IPv4 address couldn't be found...");
    return null;
}
```

**Edit 5 years later** :
In the mean time I have found a better way of getting the local IP address. You basically make a DNS request to Google's DNS server (or anything else) and see what is the source IP that is picked up by your PC.

```cs
public static string GetLocalIp() {
    using(var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0)) {
        socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
        if (!(socket.LocalEndPoint is IPEndPoint endPoint) || endPoint.Address == null) {

            return null;
        }

        return endPoint.Address.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update, I just tried your method.
Seems to work fine under Windows.
However, be careful with .NET Core (2.1) under Linux (tested on Linux container via Docker): the AddressPreferredLifetime property is NOT supported there, so it is better NOT to use it if you want cross platform code!

Comment: But i have two network card with default gateway set

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Please see my updated answer (yes I know this is a late reply)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my friend, you can do the following:

```
var nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var networkInterface in nics)
{
    if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        var address = networkInterface.GetPhysicalAddress();
    }
}
```

the address variable gives you access to PhysicalAddress of currently Up network interface

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem with this type of implementation is that it will give you out all the inytefaces that are UP. And my other cards are up also. I have posted the solution that I finally came up with

Comment: Yes, but you have selected the first one in the code sample in your question. my solution showed you all of the interfaces and you could select one of them. BTW, you found your answer and that is what that matters