# gRPC DNS resolution failed when using machine name

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I am new to gRPC and trying to learn it by using the chat server/client sample from cactuaroid [here](https://github.com/cactuaroid/GrpcWpfSample). I’ve modified the code to show progress in a WPF app from a long running task. All code is running on .NET 5 and I’m using the latest versions of the gRPC packages.

The process is working fine when using the computer's IP address but when using computer name for the gRPC client, I’m getting a “DNS resolution failed” exception (computer name is “skylake”):

> RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="DNS resolution
> failed for service: skylake:6001",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1615312867.300000000","description":"Resolver transient
> failure","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":2138,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1615312867.300000000","description":"DNS
> resolution failed for service:
> skylake:6001","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":362,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1615312867.300000000","description":"C-ares
> status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=AAAA name=skylake is_balancer=0:
> Could not contact DNS
> servers","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":716,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1615312866.142000000","description":"C-ares
> status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=skylake is_balancer=0: Could
> not contact DNS
> servers","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":716}]}]}]}")

I verified that I could reach the port with telnet skylake 6001.
I am testing locally, client and server both on the same machine. Oddly enough, the gRPC server seems to be just fine with the computer name.  Its just the client that has an issue with it.

Server code:

```
[Export(typeof(IService))]
    public class ProgressServiceGrpcServer : Progress.ProgressBase, IService
    {
        [Import]
        private Logger m_logger = null;

        [Import]
        private ProgressService m_progressService = null;
        private readonly Empty m_empty = new Empty();

        private const int Port = 6001;
        private readonly Grpc.Core.Server m_server;

        public ProgressServiceGrpcServer()
        {
            m_server = new Grpc.Core.Server
            {
                Services =
                {
                    Progress.BindService(this)
                        .Intercept(new IpAddressAuthenticator())
                },
                Ports =
                {
                    new ServerPort("skylake", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure)
                }
            };
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            m_server.Start();
            m_logger.Info("Started.");
        }

        public override async Task Subscribe(ChannelName channelName, IServerStreamWriter<ProgressReport> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            context.CancellationToken.Register(() => m_logger.Info($"{context.Host} cancels subscription."));

            try
            {
                await m_progressService.GetProgressReportsAsObservable(channelName)
                    .ToAsyncEnumerable()
      .ForEachAwaitAsync(async (x) => await responseStream.WriteAsync(x), context.CancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                m_logger.Info($"{context.Host} unsubscribed.");
            }
        }

        public override Task<Empty> Write(ProgressReport request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            m_logger.Info($"{context.Host} {request}");
            m_progressService.Add(request);
            return Task.FromResult(m_empty);
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
public class ProgressServiceClient
    {
        private readonly Progress.ProgressClient m_client =
            new Progress.ProgressClient(
                new Channel("skylake”, 6001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure));

        public async Task Write(ProgressReport progressReport)
        {
            await m_client.WriteAsync(progressReport);
        }

        public IAsyncEnumerable<ProgressReport> ProgressReports(ChannelName channelName)
        {
            var call = m_client.Subscribe(channelName);

            return call.ResponseStream
                .ToAsyncEnumerable()
                .Finally(() => call.Dispose());
        }
    }
```

Progress write method:

```
while (inProgress)
            {
                progressServiceClient.Write(new GrpcServer.ProgressReport
                {
                    Id = Task.Id.ToString(),
                    PercentDone = percentDone,
                    TimeRemain = timeRemain
                }).Wait();

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

Progress read method:

```
m_progressService = new ProgressServiceClient();
ChannelName channelName = new ChannelName() { Id = id };

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _ = m_progressService.ProgressReports(channelName)
                .ForEachAsync((x) =>
                {
                    Log.Debug($"id: {x.Id} progress: {x.PercentDone}");
                }, cts.Token);

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Application.Current.Exit += (_, __) => cts.Cancel();
                this.Unloaded += (_, __) => cts.Cancel();
            });
```

Comment: From cmd.exe use >Ping skylake.  If ping doesn't work then it is not your code.  IP routing (using adress and mask) can either use an IP address or go to a DNS server to get the route.  You may not be using the correct DNS server or the machine name is not in the DNS server.

Comment: Ping is working.

Comment: Fromcmd.exe use >IPConfig/all to see the DNS server info.  Something is different between the standard DNS on the machine you are doing in c#.

Comment: Host name is Skylake as written in the code. DNS Suffix Search List is "lan" and DNS Server is 192.168.1.1. What else should I be looking for?

Comment: It seems to be working when adding the suffix (i.e. skylake.lan). Question now is how to get the suffix in code.

Comment: Does the file exist : \src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jdweng for pointing me in the right direction, this was solved by adding the DNS suffix to the hostname (skylake.lan in my case).
We can get the DNS suffix via IPInterfaceProperties.DnsSuffix.

Alternatively, (which might be safer) we can use the correct IP address instead of the host name by using something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44618985/5853043).